# Create a Python package from C++ library

Tags: python, c++, package

I've been researching the topic of using C++ code in Python, but haven't found a generic clean flexible way to wrap C++ library in the Python package.

The question is whether it's possible to use existing complex C++ library to create a **regular** Python library, that can be called exactly like native Python libraries, such as NumPy or SciPy. If yes, any references would be much appreciated. If there are examples/tutorials available - it would be even more useful.

Thanks

Comment: You should read the official docs on [Extending Python with C and C++](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many, many ways.  Boost Python, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/ , is very C++-specific and exploits C++ templates to the hilt (like all of Boost!-).  Part of more general (less C++ specific) approaches include manual C coding of Python extensions, per https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html ; SWIG, per http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html ; Cython, per http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html ; ... and no doubt others I haven't come across yet.

The very existence of so many strong, actively maintained alternatives, hints that there's no "one size fits all" here!  If you're a template wizard I bet you'll swear by Boost; if you're not, I guess you're more likely to swear *at* it -- and so on, and so forth.

Personally, I tend to end up using Cython (or even just `ctypes`!-) for experimenting, manual extension coding when I decide I want to do a lot of Python work using a certain C++ library (and performance is crucial) -- and SWIG at work, because that's the standard there.  Haven't seriously used Boost in far too long -- a refresh on it goes on my not-so-tiny todo list for when my spare time gets more copious...:-).